# R - mlr positive class changed

Tags: r, mlr

I'm using R mlr package because it allows me to use multiple classification methods and tune parameters, with the same methods in this package.

But it changed my Positive Class.

In my dataset, I need to predict "HasWriteOff", it has value "1" or "2". "1" is the majority class, much more than the number of "2", which means the class is imbalanced.
I set the Positive class as "2" in `makeClassifTask` function, but after prediction, when I was checking confusion matrix, it shows Positive Class as "1".

Here is my code:

**I set the positive class here**

```
train_task <- makeClassifTask(data=data.frame(train_data), target = "HasWriteOff", positive = "2")
test_task <- makeClassifTask(data=data.frame(test_data), target = "HasWriteOff", positive = "2")
```

**train and predict with XGBoost**

```
set.seed(410)
getParamSet("classif.xgboost")
xg_learner <- makeLearner("classif.xgboost", predict.type = "response")
xg_learner$par.vals <- list(
  objective = "binary:logistic",
  eval_metric = "error",
  nrounds = 250
)
xg_param <- makeParamSet(
  makeIntegerParam("nrounds",lower=200,upper=600),
  makeIntegerParam("max_depth",lower=3,upper=20),
  makeNumericParam("lambda",lower=0.55,upper=0.60),
  makeNumericParam("eta", lower = 0.001, upper = 0.5),
  makeNumericParam("subsample", lower = 0.10, upper = 0.80),
  makeNumericParam("min_child_weight",lower=1,upper=5),
  makeNumericParam("colsample_bytree",lower = 0.2,upper = 0.8)
)
rancontrol <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 100L)
cv_xg <- makeResampleDesc("CV",iters = 3L)
xg_tune <- tuneParams(learner = xg_learner, task = train_task, resampling = cv_xg,measures = acc,par.set = xg_param, control = rancontrol)
xg_final <- setHyperPars(learner = xg_learner, par.vals = xg_tune$x)
xgmodel <- mlr::train(xg_final, train_task)
xgpredict <- predict(xgmodel, test_task)
```

**Check Confusion Matrix here**

```
nb_prediction <- xgpredict$data$response
dCM <- confusionMatrix(test_data$HasWriteOff, nb_prediction)
dCM
```

**Output**

> Accuracy : 0.9954
>                    95% CI : (0.9916, 0.9978)
>       No Information Rate : 0.9784
>       P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 5.136e-11
>                     Kappa : 0.8913
>    Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 1
>               Sensitivity : 0.9977
>               Specificity : 0.8936
>            Pos Pred Value : 0.9977
>            Neg Pred Value : 0.8936
>                Prevalence : 0.9784
>            Detection Rate : 0.9761
>      Detection Prevalence : 0.9784
>         Balanced Accuracy : 0.9456
>          'Positive' Class : 1

As you can see here 'Positive' Class is 1.

I have checked other methods I'm using here, they don't have 'positive' parameter to set.

Do you know how can I really set positive class as the minority class "2"?
I'm trying to see whether by setting the minority class as Positive Class, the Specificity can be higher?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Could you provide a complete reproducible example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I just found that, this method should also change the positive class `dCM <- confusionMatrix(test_data$HasWriteOff, nb_prediction, positive = "2")`

Yesterday I didn't check `confusionMatrix` function because I thought the positive class should be defined by those methods used before `predict`.

However, just checked the R document, for `confusionMatrix`, parameter `positive`, it is saying:

> If there are only two factor levels, the first level will be used as the "positive" result

So yesterday it simply chose the majority class no matter whether I defined positive class before.

Comment: You can simply use mlr's `getConfMatrix`.

Comment: That will just return a matrix, without giving me details about Balanced Accuracy, Specificity, Sensitivity and others

Comment: You can get those with mlr as well. My point is that if you tell mlr what the positive class is, you can't expect functions from other libraries to work correctly.